# Wamp going to https even with empty folder

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I installed WAMP and put my files into the www folder in the wamp directory forgetting to remove my httaccess file changing http going to https. Now even if i empty the www folder and try to go to localhost in my browser it changes to https even if i type http://localhost and restarting wamp wont help, why ?

Comment: Clearing your cache might help, if you didn't already try that

Comment: or you can try incognito mode

Comment: wow, that actually worked... thank you!! :D